# How to detect iOS device programmatically

Tags: iphone, device, armv7

I need to know which iOS device is currently running app (saying more exactly I need to know is device armv6 or armv7). UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad() could not check is device an iPhone4S or iPhone3G. Is it possible?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to know whether it is armv6 or armv7?

Comment: I've added some feature into my project, and it causes crashes on armv6 devices (iPhone3G). I know, that the problem is in processor's architecture, but could not figure out how to solve it yet. So I decided to make a switch which turns off this feature on old devices while I'm trying to make app run on all devices

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Download https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension (UIDevice-Hardware class) and you can use these:

```
[UIDevice currentDevice] platformType]   // returns UIDevice4GiPhone
[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString] // returns @"iPhone 4G"
```

Or check if its retina

```
+ (BOOL) isRetina
{
    if([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        return [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0 ? YES : NO;

    return NO;
}
```

Or check iOs version

```
+ (BOOL) isIOS5
{
    NSString *os5 = @"5.0";
    NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

    //    currSysVer = @"5.0.1";
    if ([currSysVer compare:os5 options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending) //lower than 4
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else if ([currSysVer compare:os5 options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending) //5.0.1 and above
    {        
        return YES;
    }
    else // IOS 5
    {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: thanks! that and @Michael Dautermann's answer is exactly what I needed!

Comment: hmm you did not say that -platformString is an category for uidevice from [there](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/) ;)

Comment: -1 `[[UIDevice currentDevice] platformString]` didn't work for me.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you have to download this https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/

Comment: Revoked my -1 and edited your post to post the url at the top with the code block (more helpful at a glance that way).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to know (at run time) if you are running on arm6 or arm7, you can use "`NXGetArchInfoFromCPUType`" ([much more detail is available in the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567215/how-to-determine-binary-image-architecture-at-runtime)).

Otherwise you can use platformType or platformString, as our incredibly quick answering friend Omar suggested (and +1 to him!).

Comment: did I say aggressive?  what I meant was "darn, you're super fast in answering".  Probably another month or so and you'll catch up to me in terms of points.

Comment: thanks for the link, it will be really helpful! and you are both quick in answering, by the way

Comment: @MichaelDautermann i wish i could reach 10K thanks for the encouragement :) ,medvedNick you are welcome