# Ios how to identify the type of equipment iphone4s and iphone5

Tags: iphone, ios, scale

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk)

Ios how to judge the type of equipment iphone3gs  iphone4  iphone4s and iphone5? i know[ [UIScreen mainScreen] scale] , but how to know the type of device, like iphone4 and iphone5

Comment: You can try [this link][1].

Hope this may help you .
Marry X-Mas


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081904/how-to-detect-ios-device-programmatically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3950748/14955 take a look at this link. take a look at this link.

Comment: thanks ,i think this link can help me

Answer (score 0):

Follow below code and it will satisfy your need.

```
#define IS_IPHONE ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] )
#define IS_IPOD   ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPod touch"] )
#define IS_IPAD   ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPad"] )
#define IS_IPHONE_5_SCREEN [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >= 568.0f && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height < 1024.0f
#define IS_IPHONE_4_SCREEN [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >= 480.0f && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height < 568.0f


if(IS_IPHONE_5_SCREEN)
{
    if(IS_IPHONE)
        NSLog(@"Hey, this is an iPhone 5 screen!");
    else if(IS_IPOD)
        NSLog(@"Hey, this is an iPod 5 screen!");
    else
        NSLog(@"Hey, this is a simulator screen with iPhone 5 screen height!");
}
else if(IS_IPHONE_4_SCREEN)
{
    if(IS_IPHONE)
        NSLog(@"Hey, this is a lower iPhone screen than 5!");
    else if(IS_IPOD)
        NSLog(@"Hey, this is a lower iPod screen than 5!");
    else
        NSLog(@"Hey, this is a lower simulator screen than 5!");
}
else if(IS_IPAD){
    NSLog(@"Hey, this is an iPad screen!");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Hey, this is an ipad simulator screen!");
}
```

Enjoy! Cheers!