# How to load multiple storyboard files depending on iOS version? (5 and 6)

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, storyboard, autolayout

I have a tab bar controller app that I am trying to make compatible for iOS 6 and iOS 5.
For iOS 6, I use auto layout.
But when trying to run on iOS 5, I get an error due to it not recognizing NSLayoutConstraints.

From what I can tell, I am required to use a different storyboard without auto layout enabled. I have copied my storyboard into a new one, but don't know how to set which storyboard to use in the app delegate.

Whats the code to do this?

Comment: Is it worth? Maintaining 2 different storyboards can be a pain. Can't you just drop iOS 5 or auto layout?

Comment: Well disabling auto layout kept causing issues with views being misaligned. But ended up doing it this way for both versions since I would have to deal with it using a 2nd storyboard anyways.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your app delegate, you should find code like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This is where you can add some code to choose among the several storyboards that you have [depending on the version of iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11081904/335858):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard;
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
if (...) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard-v5" bundle:nil];
} else {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard-v6" bundle:nil];
}
self.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Works. But ended up using one storyboard and disabling auto layout and dealing with all the re-setting of struts and springs. Answer is correct for the question though. Thanks!