# My empty swift app crashes on xcode6-beta with deployment target 7.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

My objective is to verify that swift apps/code can run on iOS 7 simulators
I am following this question [Do Swift-based applications work on OS X 10.9/iOS 7 and lower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001778/do-swift-based-apps-work-on-os-x-10-9-ios-7-and-lower/24038727#24038727?s=81ed957e1919466fae9d3d0a60a5e59c)
and specifically this answer -by @Anil https://stackoverflow.com/a/24038997

The following are the steps I followed

1. Installed xcode6 beta
2. Installed iOS 7.1 simulator from Xcode6->Preferences->Downloads
3. Now, I created a new iOS Application Master Detail project and selected swift as language
4. With default settings I was able to run the app
5. Now I changed the simulator to iPhone 5- 7.1 by following this -https://stackoverflow.com/a/24038727 and changing the deployment target to 7.1.
6. Now I can see my iOS 7.1 simulators
   When i try to run it I get build succeeded but the app crashes with swift dynamic cast excption

> libswift_stdlib_core.dylib`swift_dynamicCast:

Comment: Try it on iPad. Your issue could be caused by the new `UISplitViewController` stuff. The documentation for that class says: `in previous versions of iOS, the class is available only on iPad.`

Comment: @SantaClaus that worked! hmm, why don't you put it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Master-Detail Xcode project template creates a storyboard with a `UISplitViewController` as the root view controller.

Before iOS 8, `UISplitViewController` was iPad only. The documentation states:

> In iOS 8 and later, you can use the UISplitViewController class on all
>   iOS devices; in previous versions of iOS, the class is available only
>   on iPad.

You *might* want to [load a different storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15725063/2446155) for devices running an older version of iOS. I've been wondering how apple wants us to approach this with iOS 8. It might be a good idea to read up on what Apple calls `Adaptive View Controllers`, or watch [a WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) on them. I believe "Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit" covers the new functionality of `UISplitViewController`