# Detect cpusubtype iPhone

Tags: c++, objective-c, theos

I am trying to get the cpusubtype of the device where my app is running .
Is there any chance to only get the cpusubtype?
Referring to this: [Detect processor ArmV7 vs ArmV7s. Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609213/detect-processor-armv7-vs-armv7s-objective-c)

```
sysctlbyname("hw.cpusubtype", &value, &length, NULL, 0);
```

Will it return numbers like 9,11,12,64 ? If yes can I then just use

```
if hw.cpusubtype(64){
//code for arm64
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from the thread [Detect processor ArmV7 vs ArmV7s. Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609213/detect-processor-armv7-vs-armv7s-objective-c) that you linked to

```
int32_t value = 0;
size_t length = sizeof(value);
sysctlbyname("hw.cpusubtype", &value, &length, NULL, 0);
```

puts the CPU subtype into the `value` variable, so you would compare that with the
subtypes defined in `<mach/machine.h>`, for example:

```
if (value == CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM_V7) {
    // ...        
}
```

But if your intention is to check if your app is running on a 32-bit or a 64-bit 
processor then you have to get the "cputype", and not "cpusubtype", as demonstrated
here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20105134/1187415:

```
sysctlbyname("hw.cputype", &value, &length, NULL, 0);

if (value == CPU_TYPE_ARM64) {
    // ARM 64-bit CPU
} else if (value == CPU_TYPE_ARM) {
    // ARM 32-bit CPU
} else {
    // Something else.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help . The problem with "hw.cputype" is if the device is arm64 but still run the armv7 or amrv7s part of the app my code won't work .

Comment: @user3452589: Your question was how to detect the CPU subtype. If this does not answer your question then you have to provide more information about your actual problem.

Comment: no everything is fine :) thank you again the first code is just fine because it can detect even the 7s , whats not possible with the second code .